When running npx creat-vue gives me an error message, and can not create-vue app
I am trying to create a vuejs aplication using npx, but the npx create-vue app command line it gives the error below. The node version is
v12.22.9 and the npm version is 8.5.1.
> home/myuser/.npm/_npx/d8a5db81a46afa44/node_modules/create-vue/outfile.cjs:4486


const isFeatureFlagsUsed = typeof (argv.default ?? (argv.ts || argv.typescript) ?? argv.jsx ?? (argv.router || argv["vue-router"]) ?? argv.pinia ?? (argv.tests || argv["with-tests"]) ?? argv.vitest ?? argv.cypress ?? argv.nightwatch ?? argv.playwright ?? argv.eslint ?? argv["eslint-with-prettier"] ?? (argv.devtools || argv["vue-devtools"])) === "boolean";
^


SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

How can I solve this error message?

Give Node v20 a try. Then maybe try to install the CLI locally then if it still doesn't work with npx.

It just work, thank you @kissu

OP achieved to have a working solution by using Node v20.
Node v12 was indeed a very old version that needed to be bumped.
